# How to improve replacement of elements in a std::vector?

Tags: c++, stdvector

I am working on the code shown below. Basically I have a global variable, called gParams, that is a std::vector of a data type I defined, called Parameter. Parameter is a struct with 3 fields.
There is also a function, named set_params, accepting a std::vector of Parameter.

I want to modify this global variable using the following logic: every element in the std::vector passed as an argument to set_params() has to replace the corresponding element in the global variable.

In what I wrote, you can see I am using the name of the parameter (passed to the function) just to identify it in the global variable and then replace it.

This is working properly, but I would like to understand if the same goal can be achieve with something different, maybe more efficient since I am using a for loop and an algorithm inside. The only **constraint** I have is that **I have to use vectors**.
Any ideas?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct Parameter
{
  std::string name{"Default"};
  int value{0};
  float status{0.0};
};

std::vector<Parameter> gParams{{"Param1",1},
                               {"Param2",2},
                               {"Param3",3},
                               {"Param4",4},
                               {"Param5",5}};

void printParams()
{
  for(auto& param : gParams)
  {
    std::cout << param.name << "\t" << param.value << "\t" << param.status <<  std::endl;
  }
}

void set_params(std::vector<Parameter> newParams)
{
  for(auto& newParam : newParams)
  {
    std::replace_if(gParams.begin(), 
                    gParams.end(),
                    [&](const auto& gParam){return (newParam.name == gParam.name);},
                    newParam);
  }
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Before set" << std::endl;
  printParams();


  std::vector<Parameter> newParams{{"Param5", 10},{"Param3", 6}};
  set_params(newParams);

  std::cout << std::endl;

  std::cout << "After set" << std::endl;
  printParams();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the vector is sorted by name then use std::lower_bound.

Comment: If the names are unique, this should imho be `auto pos = std::find_if(gParams.begin(), gParams.end(), [&newParam](Parameter const& e) { return e.name == newParam.name; }); if (pos != gParams.end()) { pos->value = newParam.value; pos->status = newParam.status; }`. (or at least `*pos = std::move(newParam);` in the `if` body) to avoid using the copy constructor of `std::string` used by the implicitly defined copy constructor of `Parameter`...

Comment: @CepBoy Why this limitation? But if you sort the vector once (std::sort) you can at least us binary search to find the replacement point in O(log n) instead of O(n)

Comment: Even if the parameters are in the form of `vector<Parameter>`, you could have a helper `std::map` from strings to `Parameter*`, to speed up the lookup. However, if the parameter list is never going to get very big, then then O(n^2) algorithm is probably good enough.

Comment: OP mentioned, IN BOLD, that `std::vector` is a constraint and the ONLY constraint. So, no point to offer OP `std::map` or other container solution.